# Why does javascript: on webview lead to a new page?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

So I've been trying to search around the internet if there was a something similar, but I just couldn't find what I was looking for.

Anyways, my question is when using `webview.loadUrl("javascript: [javascript].value =  'value'")` or something similar to changing a property, such as `innerhtml`, it always opens the return value to a different page. I'm not sure why it does this, but on Google Chrome, it seems to do the same exact thing. All of the tutorials on how to use javascript on WebView's use the same method I use to execute javascript on a page; however, theirs don't seem to open the response onto a new page.

What I'm looking for is a way to inject javascript onto a page without it having to load separate window.

This is my code:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.carTaxWebView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      @Override
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_vin').value = '" + MainPage.getActivityInstance().getCar().getVin() + "';");
      }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("http://onlinemvd.dor.ga.gov/tap/option1.aspx#message");
```

I want it to automatically fill in the VIN code once the user loads the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Chrome and newer versions of WebView, if a `javascript:` URL returns a value, this value is interpreted as content for a new web page to open. There are two ways to prevent this:

1. Use `WebView.evaluateJavascript()` [(doc)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback<java.lang.String>)) instead of `WebView.loadUrl("javascript:...")`. This also has the virtue of being able to return the result of the evaluation back to Java without using injected Java objects.
2. Make your evaluated Javascript code not to return value, like this:

   - `javascript:doSomething();void(0);`
   - `javascript:(function(){doSomething();})();`

   The second form has the advantage that any declared variables will not spill out into the global context.

Comment: Looks like that method was introduced on Android 22, I'm still on 21, but my phone uses Lollipop 5.0.1. The latter works for my situation, so thanks a lot!

Comment: `evaluateJavascript` method was been added in API level 19 (KitKat). Check out what `minimumSdkLevel` is specified in your app's manifest, if it appears like you can't use it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 21 as min, so that's weird.